# Flex seems do not support a regex lookahead assertion (the fast lex analyzer)

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

When I tried to use regex in flex as following to define an int type:

```
int    (?<!\w)(([1-9]\d*)|0)(?!\w)
```

I meant to make this invalid:

```
int a = 123;
int b = 123f; //the '123' should not filtered as an int type
```

However, I got this:

```
bad character: <
bad character: !
bad character: \
...
```

What's more, it seems that the `?` in the regex was ignored.
I got confused.
Does flex not support the lookahead assertion `(?<=xxx)` or `(?<!xxx)` ?

I am new in flex, I really need some help

Comment: Look here:  http://www.stratulat.com/Regular_Expressions_Flex.html  Your regex seems to work, perhaps the problem is in your code.

Comment: Your code snippets look like C, not Actionscript.  Are you using the "fast lexical analyzer" or Adobe Flex?

Comment: Your regex works http://regexr.com?38gcv post code

Comment: I am using the fast lexical analyzer, sorry i did not mention it clearly ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's correct. Flex does not support negative lookahead assertions. It also does not support `\w` or `\d`, although it does allow posix-style character classes (`[[:alpha:]]`, `[[:digit:]]`, `[[:alnum:]]`, etc.)

Flex regular expressions are quite different from javascript-like or perl/python-like "regular" expressions. For one thing, flex's regular expressions are really regular.

A complete list of the syntaxes flex allows is in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). Anything not described in that section of the manual is *not implemented* by flex.

There is very little point using "lookbehind" with flex, because flex always matches the longest token *at the current input point*. It does not search the input for a pattern.

Flex *does* implement a limited form of positive lookahead, using the `/` operator (which is not part of any regular expression library I know of.) You could use that to only match a sequence of digits not immediately followed by a letter:

```
[[:digit:]]+/[^[:alpha:]]
```

But you'll then need some pattern which does match the sequence of digits followed by an alphabetic character, because flex does not search for a matching token.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And... can I just believe that the lookahead assertion makes the matcher much more complicated, and flex does not support it, or there are some other reasons?

Comment: @sstt: In general, lookahead assertions complicate the scanner, but flex does support positive lookahead (with some restrictions) and any regular expression can be negated into another regular expression. Any non-trivial lookahead assertion will require scanning input characters twice, so they should be avoided if you want a fast scanner. In any event, they are rarely needed in lexical analysis. For really complex lexical analysis, use start conditions to build a state machine.