# Regular expression matches any word except for some words in flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I would like to write a regular expression that matches any word.
I use `[a-zA-Z]*` except for some words, for example `WORD1` and `WORD2`.

So `somethingsomething` matches, but the words `WORD1` and `WORD2` won't. Is it possible in flex?

I have tried:

`[a-zA-Z]*|[^"WORD1""WORD2]` and `[a-zA-Z]*{-}["WORD1""WORD2"]` but neither works.

(Now I know why they don't work but I still don't know the solution.)

Comment: [Lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are not available in flex regex are they?

Comment: @bobblebubble: [It doesn't look good.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22326399/20670)

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking here. `[a-zA-Z]*` won't match `WORD1`, although it will match `WORD`. What did you want to happen when WORD1 is encountered? An error? A different token type? Two tokens? Only if we know what you want the result of scanning `WORD1` to be can we provide a suggestion for how to implement it.

Comment: What do you mean by "any word"? As in, any English word, in which case you need to allow for apostrophes (or you *won't* match words like "don't")?

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach in lex/flex is to use a combination of patterns and rules to select the desired behavior:

- You could make a lexer which matches (and ignores) those words and then falls through to the expression for other identifiers, or
- Simply match all identifiers and filter out the results with a lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a regular expression for the situation you presented.

In order to match all words except **word** you can write:

```
w|wo|wor|word[a-z]+|([^w]|w[^o]|wo[^r]|wor[^d])[a-z]*
```

But as @Thomas and @rici pointed out, you have much better solutions (specially when
you define a concrete problem).

Example: "count all words except the word **word**"  is in fact very simple (using Thomas proposal):

```
%%
  int i;

word        {    }
[a-z]+      {i++;}

.|\n        {    }
<<EOF>>     { printf("%d\n",i); return 0; }
%%
```

(untested)