# Strange bug in flex caused by reg exp

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, regex-negation

I tried to run 2 pieces of code on flex.
The first code works fine.
I changed only line 5 from "printable ([bc])" to "printable ((?!a)[abc])"
which is exactly the same meaning, and the code failed with these errors:

```
...(lots of bad character errors)
ex.lex:21: bad character: %
ex.lex:21: bad character: %
ex.lex:21: EOF encountered inside pattern
ex.lex:21: unrecognized rule
ex.lex:21: fatal parse error
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Nadav

```
This code works:(didn't add the functions' declerations)

%}
%option noyywrap
letter [a-zA-Z]
lower [a-z]
printable ([bc])
%x COMMENT
%%
\/\* BEGIN(COMMENT);
<COMMENT>\/\* error(1);
<COMMENT>\*\/ BEGIN(INITIAL);
<COMMENT>{printable}* showToken("comment");
<COMMENT>. error(1);
@import showToken("import");
@ error(2);
. showToken("idk");
%%

This code doesn't work:

...
printable ((?!a)[abc])
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flex seems do not support a regex lookahead assertion (the fast lex analyzer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326399/flex-seems-do-not-support-a-regex-lookahead-assertion-the-fast-lex-analyzer)

Comment: Say the assertion don't work. What is it you're trying to accomplish ?

Comment: It's not a "strange bug"; it's just not a supported feature in flex's flavor of regex

Comment: for the example I put simple expression. I actually need a complicated expression , but except for 2 or 3 characters.

Comment: You should perhaps ask about how to accomplish your task within the constraints of flex regular expressions.

Comment: and do you have an idea on how doing it?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but if I knew I might well be able to help. So I suggest you ask a question about what you are trying to do rather than this one, which is about a non-existent feature which might, if it existed, help you do some unspecified computation.

Comment: Also, see this explanation of comment notification: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/212668