# The most efficient lookahead substitute for jflex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, regex-lookarounds, lexer, jflex

I am writing tokenizer in jflex. I need to match words like `interferon-a` as one token, and words like `interferon-alpha` as three.

Obvious solution would be lookaheads, but they do not work in jflex. For a similar task, I wrote a function matching one additional wildcard character after the matched pattern, checking if it is a whitespace in java code and pushing it back with or without a part of the matched string.

`REGEX = [:letter:]+\-[:letter:]\.`

From string `interferon-alpha` it would match `interferon-al`.
Then, in Java code section it would check if the last character of the match is a whitespace. It is not, so `-al` would be pushed back and `interferon` returned.

In the case of `interferon-a`, whitespace would be pushed back and `interferon` returned.

However, this function does not work if matched string does not have anything succeeding. Also, it seems quite clunky. Hence, I was wondering if there is any 'nicer' way of ensuring that the following character is a whitespace without actually matching and returning it.

Answer (score 4):

JFlex certainly has a lookahead facility, the same as (f)lex. Unlike Java regex lookahead assertions, the JFlex lookahead can only be applied at the end of a match, but it is otherwise similar. It is described in the [Semantics section of JFlex manual](https://jflex.de/manual.html#Semantics):

> In a lexical rule, a regular expression `r` may be followed by a look-ahead expression. A look-ahead expression is either `$` (the end of line operator) or `/` followed by an arbitrary regular expression. In both cases the look-ahead is not consumed and not included in the matched text region, but it **is** considered while determining which rule has the longest match…

So you could certainly write the rule:

```
[:letter:]+\-[:letter:]/\s
```

However, you cannot put such a rule in a macro definition (`REGEX = …`), as the manual also mentions (in the [section on macros](https://jflex.de/manual.html#MacroDefs)):

> The regular expression on the right hand side must be well formed and must not contain the `^`, `/` or `$` operators.

So the lookahead operator can only be used in a pattern rule.

Note that `\s` matches any whitespace character, including newline characters, while `.` does **not** match any newline character. I think that's what lead to your comment that `REGEX = [:letter:]+\-[:letter:]\.` "does not work if matched string does not have anything succeeding" (I'm guessing that you meant "does not have anything succeeding it *on the same line*, and also that you intended to write `.` rather than `\.`).

Rather than testing for following whitespace, you might (depending on your language) prefer to test for a non-word character:

```
[:letter:]+\-[:letter:]/\W
```

or to craft a more precise specification as a set of Unicode properties, as in the definition of `\W` (also found in the linked section of the JFlex manual).

Having said all that, I'd like to repeat the advice from [my previous answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084050/1566221) of yours: put more specific patterns first. For example, using the following pair of patterns will guarantee that the first one picks up words with a single letter suffix, while avoiding the need to explicitly pushback.

```
[:letter:]+(-[:letter:])?   { /* matches 'interferon' or 'interferon-a' */ }
[:letter:]+/-[:letter:]+    { /* matches only 'interferon' from 'interferon-alpha' */ }
```

Of course, in this case you could easily avoid the collision between the second pattern and the first pattern by using `{2,}` instead of `+` for the second repetition, but it's perfectly OK to rely on pattern ordering since it's often inconvenient to guarantee that patterns don't overlap.

Comment: I am not sure if this is Maven problem, but I am not able to compile anything with / or $ - e.g. your regular expression causes a build error. This is also why I thought that JFlex does not support lookaheads.

Comment: @santiagonasar: You're right, my mistake. JFlex doesn't allow `/` in macros; I fixed the example and added a note. Also see the new note at the end of the answer.